# Angular after proxy setup the api calls are going to localhost 4200

Tags: angular, proxy

When the API is called, the log on command prompt seems okay but the path in network tab is calling `http:localhost:4200/api/users` which is wrong. Not sure what am I doing wrong. The proxy setup path should be exactly same in the network tab.

[image: network tab]

Console.log on command prompt

[image: console.log seems fine]

`angular.json`

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "fobo-admin:build",
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
        },
......
```

My proxy settings`proxy.conf.json`

```
  {
      "/api": {
        "target": "http://3.22.22.000:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
      }
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's *supposed* to happen. The *browser* doesn't know the dev server is proxying those requests.

Comment: how do I tell the browser to redirect all the API calls to the IP I have defined ?

Comment: No, you don't. That's what the proxy is doing, *as you can see from the log*. In fact the *whole point* of using the proxy is so that the browser doesn't need to know where the backend actually is.

Comment: The browser console listens to the outgoing requests from the frontend application. In your case, the app is calling `/api/user` which will be proxy passed to your target URL. The browser does not have the knowledge of this. Could you do the request in other applications like Postman?

Comment: the IP i have posted here is wrong. Yes @MichaelD the post man return 200 status with data. Still the IP in proxy.conf.json and network tab should be same.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The browser makes the request *to the dev server*. Again, that's the whole point of the proxy.

Comment: Imagine this way, if the browser could know the actual redirected URL, why bother calling it _proxy_ then? We could simply call it the redirect config.

Comment: It wouldn't be the same. As @jonrsharpe noted, the browser makes the request to the dev server. Not to the redirected URL. The browser info is actually correct.

Comment: @MichaelD Thanks the problem was with the data. It required static V in type. Not sure why would the api maker do that. wasted my 2 hours. Thank you all for the comment.